# Can thermal fluctuations be a source spatial variation in local value of the order parameter?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Usually, textbooks point out that such spatial variations of the order parameter (or order parameter "density") can arise due to *inhomogeneous external fields* e.g., the local magnetization $m(\textbf{x})$ can vary over space when the external field is inhomogeneous $B(\textbf{x})$. For a reference see Goldenfeld page 147.

However, I can think of another source of this spatial variation, namely the *thermal fluctuations*. Even if we switch off external fields, shouldn't the thermal fluctuations cause a spatial variation in the order parameter? If not, why?

**Note** The question has been made precise after @pathintegral's response.

Answer (score 0):

By gradient term, people usually refer to the first term in 
\begin{align}
F(m)=\kappa(\nabla m)^2+rm^2+um^4+\cdots
\end{align}

First, the inhomogeneity of $m(x)$ from that of $B(x)$ does not contribute to the $\kappa(\nabla m)^2$ term. It appears in the free energy in the form of $\sim\nabla m\cdot \nabla B$.

Second, thermal fluctuations indeed contributes to gradient term $\kappa(\nabla m)^2$. In QFT the coefficient is obtained by evaluating a bubble diagram (which involves momentum and frequency summation) and expanding in terms of external momentum. At finite temperature, the frequencies are discretized into "Matsubara frequencies", given by $\Omega_m=2 m \pi T$. The $m=0$ term is usually referred to as the thermal fluctuation. Only considering this term is equivalent to reducing the field theory to statistical mechanics and hence the name.  So the thermal fluctuation is imbedded into the formulation of QFT at finite temperature.

---

**Update after question update**: I'm sure this is not the only one, but one relevant example is known as the Lifshitz transition, where upon lowering temperature or changing some other parameters the $\kappa$ term changes sign. By accounting for higher order terms, the free energy goes like
\begin{align}
F(m)=-|\kappa|(\nabla m)^2 + \beta (\nabla m)^4 + \cdots.
\end{align}
Then you see the ground state is a non-uniform state. Since as I said, the thermal fluctuations contributes to $\kappa$ term ($\beta$ term too), you can say in a loose sense that thermal fluctuations lead to a non-uniform phase.

But on the other hand, again, one typically get this effect upon *lowering* temperature. Sort of opposite to what you described, I think. This is because typically high temperature favors a more symmetric state, in this case, a uniform disordered state. There are local fluctuations to the order parameter, yes, but after statistical averaging it is uniform rather than periodically modulated like the case with a non-uniform magnetic field.

Comment: "A spatially varying order parameter can arise as a result of an inhomogeneous external field" Goldenfeld page 147 @pathintegral

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis I think your comment is either wrong or very vague. Are you saying I am equating thermal fluctuation with the fluctuation in temperature (which I am not)? Care to expand a bit?

Comment: @SRS I agree with your quotation. I am just saying inhomogeneous external field gives a gradient term like $\nabla m\cdot \nabla B$. I am just saying thermal fluctuations do contribute to a gradient term, of the form $\kappa(\nabla m)^2$.

Comment: @pathintegral : you are right. I had a false understanding of the original question.

Comment: @pathintegral I have changed the question title. I'm asking for whether the origin of the spatial variation of the order parameter is caused by thermal fluctuations.